# MYSQL union or order by?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to grab information from my database in the order that I want to.  For example, I have the names below in my database:

```
Matt
Jimmy
Craig
Jenny
Sue
```

I want to get them out in this order:

```
Sue
Craig
Jimmy
Matt
Jenny
```

How would I do that using MYSQL?

Comment: So is there any algorithm you want to use or is it just random and the database will never have any other names than these?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can do it like this (if I am understanding your requirements correctly):

```
order by field(t.name, 'Jenny', 'Matt', 'Jimmy', 'Craig', 'Sue') desc
```

EDIT:

Actually, if you want to handle a generic case with a number of already-known values of the column and the number of unknown values, the common case would be to make the known values appear in the beginning of the resultset (in the predefined order) and the rest after them. For this, you should add the predefined values in the reverse order to the `field` function argument list and make the order descending.

This way 'Sue' will go first (`field` returns 5), 'Craig' - second (4 returned) and so on up to 'Jenny'. For the values not in the argument list, `field` returns 0. So they will go to the end of the resultset.

Reference: [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ORDER BY CASE t.name 
           WHEN 'Sue' THEN 1 
           WHEN 'Craig' THEN 2
           WHEN 'Jimmy' THEN 3
           WHEN 'Matt' THEN 4
           WHEN 'Jenny' THEN 5
           ELSE 6
          END
```

It's using a CASE statement to assign an arbitrary value based on the value for ordering.